# Java Regex : Extract a specific pattern from a string "I_INSERT_TO_TOPIC_345674_123456_4.json"

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract only "_123456_4" from this string using java Regex.

```
I_INSERT_TO_TOPIC_345674_123456_4.json
```

I have tried

`Pattern.compile("(_([^_]*_[^_]))")` and `Pattern.compile("_" + "([^[0-9]]*)" + "_[0-9]")` but these do not work.

Comment: The first pattern gets 3 matches as there is not dot following. You can add the dot and use a single capturing group `(_[^_]*_[^_])\\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get 2 group of digits just before .json then you can use regex group to find the required match. You can modify the pattern as per your requirement.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(_\\d+_\\d+)\\.json");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
【\_[0-9]\*\_[0-9]\*(?=\\.)】
```

You can try to see if this works

Comment: sorry,I didn't notice that markdown made some characters undisplayed

Comment: You need to format it as code to ensure that all of the characters are displayed. The [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will help.